# Redirect to Previous Page In Angular

Tags: angular, parameters, pagination, angular2-services, angular-services

I have installed a package called ngx-pagination. But i have a problem since when you navigate away from the previous page and you click the back button, it redirects you to the first page instead of going back to the previous page? How can i make it return to the previous page if i click the back button in the browser? Here's my code below.

> TS

```
     config: any; 

     constructor() {
        this.config = {
                currentPage: 1,
                itemsPerPage: 2
            };

         this.route.paramMap
            .map(params => params.get('page'))
            .subscribe(page => this.config.currentPage = page);
            }
      }

      ngOnInit() {
            this.getAllBooks();


      }

      pageChange(newPage: number) {
           this.router.navigate(['/books'], { queryParams: { page: newPage } });
  }

        getAllBooks() {
            this.subscription = this.booksService.getAll()
            .subscribe(
                (data:any) => {
                    this.books = data;
                console.log(data);
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
```

> HTML

```
<tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let book of books | paginate: { itemsPerPage: config.itemsPerPage, currentPage: config.currentPage }">
            <td>{{ book.SKU }}</td>
            <td>{{ book.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ book.description }}</td>
         </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <pagination-controls (pageChange)=“pageChange($event)” class="my-pagination"></pagination-controls>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing is because of navigation :

```
pageChange(newPage: number) {
    this.router.navigate(['/books'], { queryParams: { page: newPage } });
}
```

You should not call `this.router.navigate`, instead of that directly call it like :

```
constructor() {
    let currentPage = localStorage.getItem('currentPage');
    this.config = {
        currentPage: currentPage ? currentPage : 1 ,
        itemsPerPage: 2
    };
}

pageChange(newPage: number) {
    localStorage.setItem('currentPage', newPage);
    this.config.currentPage = newPage;
}
```

Comment: I need the query params since when i navigate to another menu and when i click the back button, it resets to the first page

Comment: This will also do the same, try out this code and check your possibilities.

Comment: Yes i tried this and it works BUT when i click the other menu and when i return back it resets me to the first page. Because yours doesnt have the query params in the URL.

Comment: okay so you want it to be on some page from where user has left?

Comment: Yes thats why ive uses the query params

Comment: It works but the proper way is to have query params in the url. Thats what the author says. Can you take a look at what the author says in this issue https://github.com/michaelbromley/ngx-pagination/issues/174. Anyway i'll upvote your answer. Thanks Vivek

Comment: @Joseph, will you please explain me the full scenario ? how it should work from the beggining?

Comment: The same things on how your code works expect it has something like this in the url localhost:4200/book?page=3. It doesnt need to store it in the localstorage but holds the pagination state through the url params.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you’re facing is because your are not using the router to store the current page. So when you click the back button on the browser it will do a router navigation and not a pagination navigation.

So instead of only updating the current page on the control, what you need to do is also store the page in the router every time a page is changed and do a navigation. This way independently if you navigate back and forth on the browser buttons the page number is always in sync.

The other advantage of using this approach is that you will be able to open the url on a new tab and start on the correct page, or even share with someone else and it will point directly on the page you are expecting, instead of resetting it to the first page.

You can check an example of implementation [here](https://github.com/michaelbromley/ngx-pagination/issues/174), on the documentation of the ngx-pagination itself.

Comment: I can give you a hand by explaining whichever you might not understand from the provided example. But you have to try and build it first :)

Comment: I've edited my code. I believe i'm near but still can't get it. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: On your html there’s a mistake. You have the currentPage pointing to config.itemsPerPage instead of config.currentPage

Comment: I've just edited it. But still there's a problem. When i click the second page it shows a lot of pages and also the infinity button

Comment: OK from what I see in the documentation you have another mistake. So the pageChange event sends you the page number. And you are setting config to that instead of config.currentPage. I believe this is messing up your setup. I think you should be doing (pageChange)=“config.currentPage=$event”

Comment: Wait a minute you’re not calling the pageChange function that you setup in the component. You’re not actually doing the navigation are you? You should probably be doing (pageChange)=“pageChange($event)”. This way you will be sending the pages captured from the event to your function that will then use it to navigate with the router

Comment: Ive seen the url changing. But i still cant navigate from second page or another page

Comment: Can you check if after navigating it goes inside the subscriber? I’m suspecting it’s not. Try moving the code for the subscription inside the constructor instead of ngInit.

Comment: I tried to moved it to the constructor and it doesn't work still. I also console.log and it outputs "null"

Comment: Without seeing the whole code is a bit tricky. I’m assuming you defined the routing in the module with the parameter? { path: books/:page, component:<the name of your component> } something like this. You did setup the routing in the module, correct? Maybe if you can create a stackblitz with your code I will be able to have a better look and try to figure out what’s missing.

Comment: Yes the routing is correct. The problem is on the pagination only. I can see the url changing but im not able to change pages

Comment: Are you using a router-outlet? Otherwise the router navigation won’t know where to change the content.

Comment: Yes Im using router outlet

Comment: OK. Well in that I would need to have running code to be able to test it and figure out the problem. Try to create a stackblitz with the minimal needed code that reflects the scenario you’re trying to achieve and I can have a look a solve the problem.